# Text in image caption is not correct

Tags: graphics, symbols, captions

I have a figure and in the caption, I want to write $w_0 = -10^{-4}$. However, for some reason, the minus signs are not there when I compile. Any ideas why the minus signs does not show in the caption?

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[angle=0, width=0.9\linewidth]{kkltpotential.png}
\caption{Plot of the potential (multiplied by $10^{15}$), where $W_0 = −10^{−4}$, $A 
= 1$, $a = 0.1$ and the number of $\overline{D3}$-branes are  $p=0$ (blue),  $p=4$ 
(yellow) and $p=11$ (green).}
\label{fig.5}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: You should know that there are some symbols that look like a minus sign. Such `hyphens` aren't recognized in math mode.

Comment: I just came back to replace my comment but @campa beat me to it:-)

Comment: @M.A.Bromuela but in this case it _is_ the minus sign not a dash (but it is not recognised as such by design, essentially)

Comment: One of the reason could be copying text from MS-Word. There are cases such as this when the minus sign that you think it is in MS Word is not recognized in math mode.

Comment: @campa or we could make it work of course.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I don't recall having copied pasted a dash sign. I simply use the same minus sign on the Mac keyboard that I do for equations. But copy-pasting (U+002D) from online, for the minus sign works.

Comment: It's very weird if you can get U+2212 from a keyboard and can't get an ASCII hyphen -. How would you type X-ray?  But perhaps your editor is trying to be over clever and do math, but also in general after any error the PDF output isn't intended to be usable. If you want help with an error it's better to ask about the error message than the output,

Comment: @JohnGreger I am just trying to emphasize that it's very common to not tell the difference between the minus sign and the hyphen-minus. Most people aren't used to differentiate them by their unicode. They just see what they think they see. I had once tried using GrindEQ to convert my Word content to LaTeX. This application didn't accurately typeset the content entirely. It typeset what I perceived as minus sign to be U+2212. And yeah U+002D works, because that's the `hyphen-minus` we usually have in PC keyboard.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
$W_0 = −10^{−4}$,
\end{document}
```

Produces

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character − (U+2212)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.4 $W_0 = −
              10^{−4}$,
?
```

Don't ignore error messages!

In pdflatex you need an ascii `-` not the Unicode `−` (U+2212)